# How to enforce a unique list of names associated with a name in another table

Tags: sql

Consider two related tables, T1 and T2, where the T2.T1_ID values refer to T1.ID values.
I'm looking for how to use a constraint, unique index, clever insert/select, or some other approach to prevent ending up with a duplicate T1.NAME associated with the same list of T2.NAMES.

Table T1

```
ID   NAME
 1  'fred'
```

Table T2

```
T1_ID  NAME
  1    'joe'
  1    'jane'
```

So, 'fred' is associated with 'joe' and 'jane'. I want to *prevent* inserting into T1 and T2 such that I end up more than one T1 NAME with the same associated T2 NAMEs.

That is, I want the overall attempt to do the following inserts to fail:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'fred');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'joe');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'jane');
```

Because it would result in the following (invalid) table contents:

Table T1

```
ID   NAME
 1  'fred'
 3  'fred'
```

Table T2

```
T1_ID  NAME
  1    'joe'
  1    'jane'
  3    'joe'
  3    'jane'
```

That is, 'fred' would be associated with the list 'joe' and 'jane' twice.

Note that it would be *ok* for there to be a *different list* of T2 NAMEs associated with the same T1 NAME. That is, the following should be allowed:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'fred');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'joe');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'jane');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'kimberly');
```

Because it would result in the following (*valid*) table contents:

Table T1

```
ID   NAME
 1  'fred'
 3  'fred'
```

Table T2

```
T1_ID  NAME
  1    'joe'
  1    'jane'
  3    'joe'
  3    'jane'
  3    'kimberly'
```

The following would also be ok:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'fred');
INSERT INTO T2 (T1_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'joe');
```

Because it would result in the following (*valid*) table contents:

Table T1

```
ID   NAME
 1  'fred'
 3  'fred'
```

Table T2

```
T1_ID  NAME
  1    'joe'
  1    'jane'
  3    'joe'
```

Comment: You can use begin/commit/rollback transaction and check while inside the transaction if the situation would arise and rollback if necessary. The actual syntax depends on the rdbms product you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @tinazmu! That seems promising. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should restruchtire your design

First have one name table

user_table

```
ID   NAME
 1  'fred'
 2  'jane'
 3  'joe'
 4  'kimberly'
```

Her eon ID is promary KEY and  NAE gets ban Unique constraint

And a second table relationships

```
FK_ID1 FK_ID2
1      2
1      3
2      4
```

her you have a Priomary key (FK_ID1,FK_ID2)

this will enforce that fred only can befriend jane once, because adding another row would violate the primary key constraint

From my comment:

if you need to know if Fred has the same friends as Jane. the count would be 0

```
SELECt Count(*) 
FROM (SELECT FK_ID2 FROM relationships WHERE FK_ID1  = 1) f1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_ID2 FROM relationships WHERE FK_ID1  = 2) f2 ON  f1.FK_ID2 = f2. FK_ID2 
WHERE f2. FK_ID2 is NULL
```

such bridge table, that define relationships between two entities can contain additional columns, but you should also keep normalisation in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @nbk. However, if I understand your suggestion, I'm afraid this would not work for me because I need it to be ok for fred to befriend jane twice (or more) as long as the befriended lists are different. That is, it should be ok for fred to also befriend just jane, or to also befriend jane and joe. (I guess friendship isn't quite the right analogy here.)

Comment: i can't see why do you need for joe 2 rows, for more optuions you add to the second table a column or two that define additional information and you can check easy with`SELECt Count(*) FROM (SELECT FK_ID2 FROM relationships WHERE FK_ID1  = 1) f1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_ID2 FROM relationships WHERE FK_ID1  = 2) f2 ON  f1.FK_ID2 = f2. FK_ID2 WHERE f2. FK_ID2 is NULL`with the count if joe has the same friends as Jane, If you want to know teh same for Joe an Fred you simply chage the ids, so basically every information is alre3ady there